# CRM 2011 FetchXml to pull list accounts and display only most recent activity dates

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, fetchxml

I am trying to create a report in fetchxml on crm 2011 that displays a list of Account Names, and also in the same row displays the date of ONLY the most recent activity for that account.

So

Report should look like

```
Account1, Date of most recent activity for Account 1
Account2, Date of most recent activity for Account 2
Account3, Date of most recent activity for Account 3
```

I have a fetch query that pulls the correct data, but it pulls a row for each activity for the account instead of just for the newest activity.

so it looks like

```
Account1, Date of most recent activity for Account 1
Account1, Date of other activity  for Account 1
Account2, Date of most recent activity for Account 2
Account2, Date of other activity for Account 2
Account3, Date of most recent activity for Account 3
```

Here is my fetch

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" aggregate="false">
    <entity name="<accountentityname>"
        <attribute name="<accountname>" />
        <link-entity name="activity" from="<regardingaccoutnfield>" to="<account field>" visible="false" link-type="outer"> 
            <attribute name="<date of activity>"  />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do requires a subquery.  This is something that [CRM does not support](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/01/14/dynamics-crm-2011-sdk-query-limitations-by-api.aspx).

If you're not using CRM Online, just perform a standard SSRS query using SQL rather then FetchXml.

If you're just trying to pull back data with the SDK, you could perform the subquery on the client side.

### Why Max Aggregate Won't Work

If your column you were wanting to get the max value on was a number you could use an aggregate, but Aggregate functions AVG, MIN, MAX, or  SUM can only be applied to attributes of type integer, float, money, bigint, or decimal.

That's the error if you attempt to run this query:

```cs
var xml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true' aggregate='true'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' alias='name' groupby='true'   />
    <attribute name='contactid' alias='id' groupby='true'  />
    <link-entity name='activitypointer' from='regardingobjectid' to='contactid' alias='ad' link-type='outer'>
      <attribute name='createdon' alias='createdon_max' aggregate='max' /> 
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='createdon' operator='not-null' />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>";

EntityCollection fetchResult = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(xml);
```

Comment: could the [maxaggregate attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#max) be of any use here?

Comment: I'm not a fetchxml expert but if you know the fetch needed to answer it, please do (I might need it someday!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the [maxaggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#max) attribute will work with datetimes, but if it does that might work

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sort on the date and return the first record only!

Do your query on accounts then return a for each & use something like:

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
      <entity name="activitypointer">
        <attribute name="scheduledstart" />
        <order attribute="scheduledstart" descending="true" />
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="scheduledstart" operator="not-null" />
        </filter>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

OR similar Query Expression:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("activitypointer");
                            query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("scheduledstart");
                            query.AddOrder("scheduledstart", OrderType.Descending);
                            EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Then something like:

```
(DateTime)(((Entity)results.Entities.First()).Attributes["scheduledstart"]);
```

Add the condition that the regarding field is equal to the account.id that's in scope for the for each loop